# How to work a method dispite it is not called in libgdx project

Tags: libgdx

I am analizing a game code.
A method which name is act() is running despite it is not called.
Its like, there is a secret method somwere but i cant see it.
i follow source of method.i find so code.The some part of codes are as below.
I think parent class send method to child class when a new object execuded.
Is there a name of this approach.

This is LevelScreen class.It does not have act() method but act() method is working.I can see the changes when i change the parametres in act() method in Plane class.

```
class LevelScreen : BaseScreen(){
 plane = Plane(100f, 500f, mainStage)}
```

This is Plane class which has act() method.

```
class Plane(x: Float, y: Float, s: Stage) : BaseActor(x, y, s){
    override fun act(dt: Float)  {
            super.act(dt)
    
            // simulate force of gravity
            setAcceleration(800f)
            accelerateAtAngle(270f)
            applyPhysics(dt)
    ................
    .............
    
    }
```

This is parent class of Plane class

```
open class BaseActor(x: Float, y: Float, s: Stage) : Group(){
override fun act(dt: Float) {
        super.act(dt)

        if (!animationPaused)
            elapsedTime += dt
    }


}
```

This is a class which is in framework of libGDX

```
public class Group extends Actor implements Cullable{
public void act (float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
        Actor[] actors = children.begin();
        for (int i = 0, n = children.size; i < n; i++)
            actors[i].act(delta);
        children.end();
    }

}
```

Comment: Set a debugger breakpoint, and check where act() is being called from (and no, it won't be executed unless it is called!)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the main project file where the **Stage** is created. The main file will have a method called **render** and this is where the **act** method is called for the first time. All Actors are added to the Stage and then inside of the render method the act method is called on the Stage, which then calls the act method on all of the Actors that it contains.

This is the section you are looking for (taken from one of my projects):

```
@Override
public void render (){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.6f, 0.64f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime());      // START OF ACT METHODS
    stage.draw();
}
```